# Issue with php5-curl installation

Tags: php

I currently have PHP 5.4.14-1~quantal+1 (cli) installed on my Ubuntu 13.04
I tried to install php5-curl but I have a dependency issue

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

"php5-curl : Depend: php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2) but 5.4.14-1~quantal+1 should be installed"

Do someone has any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps try `sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-common`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a mirror hiccup. make sure to do:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-common
```

PHP just recently upgraded and the mirror might have not synced correctly. If it continues try the next day, these things get solved quickly.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I installed php with the ppa:ondrej/php5 repository. When I updated Ubuntu (12.10 > 13.04), this repository was commented in the sources.list.